# Getting values into dropdown from DB

Tags: codeigniter, foreach, while-loop

I want to use my db values of table (Category) into a product/add form, but not able to get the values.

```
Model :
 function getAllCategories()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('category');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

 Controller:

function getAllCategories()
   {
      $data['groups'] = $this->productmodel->getAllCategories();

       $this->load->view('admin/product/add',$data);
   }   

  View:

<div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Brand </label>
                  <select class="form-control">
                <?php 
                $i = 0;
                while($i < count($groups)){
                  $val= $groups[$i]['value'];
                  $des = $groups[$i]['category_name'];
                  echo "<option value='$i'>$des</option>";
                }?>
               </select>
 </div>
```

Help me please it is urgent.I took reference from stack overflow only, but was not able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `foreach` loop for array data type

```
<select class="form-control">
<?php 
foreach($groups as $group)
{
   $val= $group['value']; 
   $des = $group['category_name'];
   echo "<option value='$val'>$des</option>";
} ?>
</select>
```

Comment: The <option> value is coming blank. The values from db are not getting print.

Comment: Print the $groups variable using print_r($groups); , you will get clear data.

Answer (score 0):

No panic it's should be easy. Do you get some data from model in controller ?
First, var_dump this line $this->productmodel->getAllCategories();
Second, I think you should do $i++ in your while cycle

Like this

```
<?php 
$i = 0;  
while($i < count($groups)){ 
  $val= $groups[$i]['value']; 
  $des = $groups[$i]['category_name']; 
  echo "<option value='$i'>$des</option>"; 
  $i++; 
}?>
```

Comment: Okay will check it sir.

Answer (score 0):

Himanshu, Simply replace your code with this one in your view.
The thing is that you are not incrementing the value of $i

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Brand </label>
    <select class="form-control">
        <?php
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < count($groups)) {
            $val = $groups[$i]['value'];
            $des = $groups[$i]['category_name'];
            echo "<option value='".$i."'>$des</option>";
            $i++;
        } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```